# How save Xrandr orientation change settings

Tags: touchscreen, display-rotation

Hello When I turn on my Lap Top the screen rotated 90 deg. (Both of login screen and desktop screen). So I use this code to rotate screen

```
xrandr -o normal
```

but the first problem is: this code is just for desktop (I need to login to computer and run this code and I can not change login screen rotation) and the second problem is: this code is temporary and I want save setting after restart

My lap top is: Asus Tp 550 LJ and has  touchscreen

Comment: I tried this option but dose not work for me .

Comment: The second answer on the duplicate has a link to Xrandr's page where you can set orientation for the login screen: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Now_automate_it_on_login